# Why didn't I receive linker error?

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

I've used this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial to make my own static library. But when I tried to use this library in some project I faced with some mysterious (for me) behaviour. If I add header files to new project (without static_library_name.a) I didn't get any linked error. Why does this happens?

Comment: What's in the headers, and are you actually referencing their contents anywhere (i.e. instantiating a class/calling a function declared within them)?

Comment: I referencing their contents using storyboard and few view controllers classes

Comment: Just checking, but you mean referenced as in "Just referenced using Interface builder", as in "Also have variables declared as pointers to those types", or "Actually instantiated classes instances or called functions"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker will only need to resolve the symbol if you're actually referencing it. Reference in this context means "Actually called a function" or "Actually instantiated a class" (which, ultimately, calls a function). Merely creating a variable of pointer type, as in:

```
Foo *aFoo;
```

is not enough to cause the definition to be needed. You need to actually invoke code, as in:

```
Foo *aFoo = [[Foo alloc] init]; // or similar
```

to need the definitions. Until the linker requires the definition, you can have as many declarations without definitions as you like, and the build process won't mind.

Comment: Yep, your answer is rock. When I've tried to actually instantiate a class from library I've got linker error. Thank you for your response. Just to clarify, is there any way to force linker or xcode to resolve dependencies without invoking code?